# WebApi async actions, do i have to create async methods through all call chain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to make my WebApi async in order not to block ASP.net threads  handling the requests while accessing the database. So I create the following code. To my understanding when this action is called a new thread away from the ASP.net thread pool is created to handle the `GetBalance` method and the thread that handled this action request in the past will get freed and returned to the pool until to be used by other requests till the GetBalance method finishes its IO. Is this correct?

Some article I have read suggests that my async calls has to go all the way through all the call chains till it reaches the lowest level async call, in this example an Entity Framework async call. Other wise the new thread created by the code below will still be created in the ASP.net thread pool and I will just be freeing a thread to occupy another, which undermines the whole effort done in the async wait to increase scalability of this WebApi.

Could anybody please explain more on how this works? and if my understanding is correct?

```
    public async Task<Account> Balance(int number)
    {
        Task<Account> task = GetBalanceAsync(number);
        await task;

        return task.Result;
    }

    Task<Account> GetBalanceAsync(int number)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetBalance(number));
    }

    Account GetBalance(int number)
    {
        using (AccountServices accountService = new AccountServices())
        {
            Account account = accountService.Find(number);

            return account;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one thread pool. ASP.NET requests just run on a regular thread pool thread.

> To my understanding when this action is called a new thread away from the ASP.net thread pool is created to handle the GetBalance method and the thread that handled this action request in the past will get freed and returned to the pool until to be used by other requests till the GetBalance method finishes its IO. Is this correct?

Yes; your code is taking one thread from the thread pool (`StartNew`), and then returning a thread to the thread pool (`await`).

> Some article I have read suggests that my async calls has to go all the way through all the call chains till it reaches the lowest level async call, in this example an Entity Framework async call. Other wise the new thread created by the code below will still be created in the ASP.net thread pool and I will just be freeing a thread to occupy another, which undermines the whole effort done in the async wait to increase scalability of this WebApi.

[Yes, that's exactly correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx). The code posted adds complexity and overhead, and will have worse performance than synchronous code:

```
public Account Balance(int number)
{
  return GetBalance(number);
}

Account GetBalance(int number)
{
  using (AccountServices accountService = new AccountServices())
  {
    return accountService.Find(number);
  }
}
```

A fully-asynchronous solution will have better scalability:

```
public async Task<Account> Balance(int number)
{
  return await GetBalanceAsync(number);
}

Task<Account> GetBalanceAsync(int number)
{
  using (AccountServices accountService = new AccountServices())
  {
    return await accountService.FindAsync(number);
  }
}
```